# Extract summary of regression model in latex

Tags: r, kable

Is there a way to extract the summary of a regression model in a nice latex format like the correlation table I attach below?

[image]

```
# install.packages("dplyr")
# install.packages("kableExtra")
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

mlm1 <- lm(mpg ~  . , data = mtcars)
summary(mlm1)


summary(mlm1) %>%
  kbl(caption="Table 1: Summary Statistics of Financial Well-Being  
               Score by Gender and Education",
       format= "html",
                  align="r") %>%
   kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "helvetica")
```

Comment: You need to use `summary(mlm1)$coef` (the data frame of coefficients) instead of `summary(mlm1)` which is a list with more information.

Comment: I want all the information from the summary print result

Comment: Well if you run your code as-is, you will see it gives an error because you cant use kable table function on a list object.

Comment: I know that I just putted as it is to show what my regression table needs to display when created

Comment: the `stargazer` package might give you most of what you want; I don't know if it includes *everything* in the `summary()` output

Comment: library(stargazer)
mlm1 <- lm(mpg ~  . , data = mtcars)

stargazer(mlm1, type="html",
          
 out="models.htm")
I get the result inside html tags though

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `type="html"` in stargazer if you want LaTeX output (which is the default anyway ...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `gt` package that is becoming the norm together with `gtsummary` that has a lot of [options and customizations for regression tables](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_regression.html).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)  
library(gtsummary)
  
mlm1 <- lm(mpg ~  . , data = mtcars)
# summary(mlm1)

mlm1 %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_regression() %>%
  gtsummary::modify_caption("Table 1: Summary Statistics of Financial Well-Being  
                            Score by Gender and Education")

# Use gt::as_latex() for Latex
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[image]

Comment: are all the summary() components included into this table?

Comment: In this simple one that I showed no, but you can add them. From APA perspective, this is all you need to show in a regression table (se and z-scores are typically omitted), but with `gtsummary` you can add more information about the model than the `summary` function provides.

Comment: as an answer I need all info provided by the summary(mlm1) in the table

Comment: I am not sure you know what the components of summary(mlm1) are. Anyway, good luck printing a table that includes residuals and unstandardized covariances.