# Extract regression summary() output in word document in a nicely formated resut

Tags: r, regression, knitr, kable

Is there a way to extract the summary of a regression model in a nice latex format like the correlation table I attach below? The table should be exported using knitr in word document or at least saved in word document.

[image]

```
# install.packages("dplyr")
# install.packages("kableExtra")
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

mlm1 <- lm(mpg ~  . , data = mtcars)
summary(mlm1)


summary(mlm1) %>%
  kbl(caption="Table 1: Summary Statistics of Financial Well-Being  
               Score by Gender and Education",
       format= "html",
                  align="r") %>%
   kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "helvetica")
```

Comment: You've already posted the identical question here [Extract summary of regression model in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833403/extract-summary-of-regression-model-in-latex). Please don't repost questions that you've already asked, especially when you've only just asked them.

Comment: this is not talking about word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `broom` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(broom)

mlm1 <- lm(mpg ~  . , data = mtcars)
summary(mlm1)

tidy(mlm1) %>%  kbl(caption="Table 1: Summary Statistics of Financial Well-Being  
               Score by Gender and Education",
                    format= "html",
                    align="r") %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "helvetica")
```

[image]

Also, you can reports information about the entire model (i.e. R-squared, AIC, ...) via `broom::glance(mlm1)`.